# R Markdown beamer title

Tags: r-markdown

I am preparing a beamer presentation with R Markdown and need to use special character in the title a “long Hungarian umlaut”. Using the character “ő” is written out as a regular “o” and using \H{o} gets execution to halt but works in regular text. Someone that know how to get around this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

What LaTex package uses the `\H{o}` command? If it needs this package, you need to include it in your markdown document

To do this, include this in your header as such:

```
---
title: TITLE
author: AUTHOR
header-includes:
- \usepackage{YOURPACKAGE}

---
```

Then, when in your title, encapsulate the command with `$\H{o}$` which should make pandoc recognize that its a latex command.

However, I am not sure if this would work if you use a latex command in the title inside the yaml header.